# How to HTTP POST a XML File using PHP without cURL?

Tags: php, xml, http-post

I have a XML created from a Table In MySql, I need to make a HTTP Post to insert the XML into a Web Service. The Web Service just accepts SOAP, HTTP POST and HTTP GET methods. I tried to make the HTTP POST request in different ways with no luck at all. I never worked with SOAP before. How can I make the HTTP POST or SOAP Request?

post_xml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?ADF version="1.0"?>
<adf>
<prospect><id sequence="1" source="xxxs">37</id>
<requestdate>2013-07-10 06:10:42</requestdate>
<vehicle interest="buy" status="new">
<year>2013</year>
<make>12</make>
<model>21</model>
<trim>Sport</trim>
</vehicle>
<customer>
<contact>
<name part="first">Jay</name>
<name part="last">11z</name>
<email>test@gmail.com</email>
<phone time="morning" type="voice" preferredcontact="1">99999999</phone>
<address>
<street line="1">1130 E Test</street>
<city>sa</city>
<regioncode>Z</regioncode>
<postalcode>79924</postalcode>
<country>USA</country>
</address>
</contact>
</prospect>
</adf>
```

client1.php (HTTP POST CODE)

```
$xml = file_get_contents('post_xml.xml');
$url = 'http://stg.sa.com/post.asmx/';

$post_data = array ("XML" => $xml);
$stream_options = array(
    $url => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . "\r\n",
        'content' => http_build_query($post_data)
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($stream_options);    
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

HTTP POST specs of the Web Service:

The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response.

```
POST /st.asmx/Post HTTP/1.1
Host: stg.sa.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
XML= string

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0"?>
xml
```

Comment: Are you sure that XML should be passed in `XML` parameter, not as request body?

Comment: yes, this is the web service post example:http://st.sa.com/ausapost.asmx/Post?XML=<?xml version="1.0"?><?ADF version="1.0"?><adf><prospect><id sequence="1" source="Provider">800</id><requestdate>2010-03-18T07:50:53-05:00</requestdate><vehicle interest="buy" status="new"><year>2004</year><make>MERCEDES-BENZ</make><model>E-Class</model><trim>E320 Rwd 4dr Sedan (3.2L 6cyl 5A)</trim></vehicle><customer><contact><name part="first">John</name><name part="last">Doe</name><email>valid@email.com</email>...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your POST array is wrong

Try:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('post_xml.xml');
$url = 'http://stg.sa.com/post.asmx/';


$post_data = array(
    "xml" => $xml,
);

$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
       'content' => http_build_query($post_data),
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

Comment: I change the $URL to 'http' in the array but still have no communication to the web service.

Comment: Thank you Dan2600, your code is the right way to make the post. My provider sent me a wrong URL.

Comment: Note that if the other end is reading this data raw with like php://input, and immediately interpreting it as XML without needing to pull it out of the associated array variable index "xml", then you should replace `http_build_query($post_data)` with simply `$xml`.