# How would I create this with PHP soap?

Tags: php, soap

I am tasked to create a web service call where the input looks like this:

```
<own:AuthenticateMember>
    <own:request>
        <own1:SecurityToken>9415CD31-0C7E-40AB-A45F-D3538B98D96D</own1:SecurityToken>
        <own2:MembershipNumber>200103407801</own2:MembershipNumber>
    </own:request>
</own:AuthenticateMember>
```

The actual values (SecurityToken and MembershipNumber) are PHP request variables.

As you see, it contains namespaces.  How would I go about successfully creating this xml request via PHP Soap?  Please help me.

Comment: Well the sample you gave us is not SOAP. You would likely need a RESTlike PHP client that would POST the XML content you have.

Comment: Try this URL - it could help http://phphttpclient.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to HTTP POST a XML File using PHP without cURL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578799/how-to-http-post-a-xml-file-using-php-without-curl)